# Computer lock up troubleshooting tips/solutions?

Tags: kernel, intel-graphics, lockup

I am using an HP 15 Notebook PC with Ubuntu and my computer frequently locks up on a ridiculous level. It's usually at least a dozen times per day. I'm sure it's a hardware problem at this point but "guaranteed" Customer Care from the manufacturer refuses to help me because I uninstalled windows from the PC (oops.) So I guess i gotta fix it from my end. Does anybody out there have some troubleshooting tips or solutions? Much appreciated.

update 1: advised to use kernel param "intel_idle.max_cstate=1" to fix an issue with Intel Bay Trail [/etc/default/grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1HBz.png)

Comment: If Ubuntu is greying out and freezing, then this is most likely either a) a harddrive failure, or b) low memory. I tend to believe it is the former. Both aren't too hard to replace given the fact that you have an HP 15.

Comment: Right, but I'm not sure that's it. I'm aware of the greying out issues but this isn't what's happening. It just freezes and I have to force shut down

Comment: Ok, can you go through the /var/log directory, view the syslog file, and see if there are any ACPI errors? Also, is your PC an Intel BayTrail-based notebook? Freezing is currently a major issue with such devices.

Comment: No I have Intel Penitum. I scanned through /var/log/syslog and didn't find ACPI errors specifically. I however got 184 hits for 'error' although I can't tell for sure how serious each may be. Annoyingly, my computer froze up again as I was searching.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a Bay Trail Pentium? There are Atom, Celeron, and Pentium models.

Comment: Hmm yeah actually it might be. I have Intel Pentium n3540. I think that is a bay trail model.

Comment: Yeah, that is a Bay Trail Pentium- try this kernel param: "intel_idle.max_cstate=1", in Grub at boot. Add it in the same line that has "quiet splash".

Comment: Alright I want to make sure I get this right. I'm looking at params right now and I found quiet splash. Should I replace 'quiet splash' with 'intel_idle.max_cstate=1' or should I add it elsewhere on the line? The line reads like this: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/Ubuntu--vg-root ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff

Comment: No, do not replace "quiet splash". Add "intel_idle.max_cstate=1" after it. I heavily recommend doing this from the bootup screen, so its temporary.

Comment: So it reads 'quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1 $vt_handoff'

Comment: @PatrickNegus alright I'll update within 24 hours if this fixed my issue or not. Thanks for your suggestion! :)

Comment: BTW, to make the changes permanent, you have to edit /etc/default/grub with that kernel param. Good luck.

Comment: @PatrickNegus alright cool its working great! so, to edit it and make it permanent, would it be alright to edit the file and replace the original read-only grub with it?

Comment: lemme make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a current bug in Intel Bay-Trail based devices involving frequent freezes, lockups and crashes, that have to do with Intel CPU Sleep States (C-states). The only current alternative, as of kernel ~4.8, is to prevent the CPU from entering C-states deeper than 1.

First, open up /etc/default/grub

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line containing `quiet splash`, and add `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` directly following it:

```
quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1
```

Save and close.

Then, run the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And you're set!

Unfortunately, this fix is very dirty and results in far higher power consumption as a result of not allowing the CPU to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, I have an Intel n3530 and 16.04 has been working well with the cstate 1 added, till the newest kernel 4.4.0-45.  Will freeze up every couple days now.  I think it depends on your exact hardware config and kernel.  15.04 every couple of weeks(no cstate), 15.10 very often with cstate, 16.04 no freeze till now with cstate.

Comment: perhaps i should use a previous kernel?